# AngularJS ng-show Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to change my UI (ON LOAD) based on whether or not a token is present. I would like to show and hide my login div and my form div based on whether or not the token is present. For whatever reason, I cannot get ng-show to work. To simplify the problem I have the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/m1q7h9fn/3/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="nh-launch">
    <div ng-show="loginView">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="formView">
        <h1>Form</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('nh-launch',[]).run(function($scope) {

var token = "valid";

    if (token == "valid") {
        $scope.loginView = false;
        $scope.formView = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    else {
        $scope.loginView = true;
        $scope.formView = false;
        $scope.$apply();
    }

});
```

Comment: Have you read the console errors?

Comment: You will need an `ng-controller` and matching controller in your javascript controlling your div. Otherwise `$scope` means nothing

Comment: Here is the console error I have: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'loginView' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change run to controller as:

```js
angular.module('nh-launch', []).controller('launch-controller', function($scope) {
    /* This run when page load... */
    $scope.loginView = false;
    $scope.formView = true;
    
    $scope.changeView = function() {
        /* This run when click button */
        $scope.token = ($scope.token == "valid" ? "" : "valid");
        $scope.loginView = $scope.token == "valid";
        $scope.formView = $scope.token != "valid";
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="nh-launch" ng-controller="launch-controller">
  <button type="button" ng-click="changeView();">Change</button>
  <div ng-show="loginView">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="formView">
    <h1>Form</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I modify this so it runs on the page load instead of a button click?

Comment: @shredMER Controllers execute on page load, so if you want a function in the controller to execute on load then you just invoke the function at the bottom of the controller.

Comment: Ok thanks, I did not realize this. I will have a lot of code to re-write. Your answer has pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

In MVC frameworks like AngularJS, the model ($scope) ties to the view. The glue connecting the two is the controller. That's why `$scope` variables should be declared in the controller. I would reorganize your code as follows

```
angular.module('nh-launch',[])
   .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var token = "valid";

        if (token == "valid") {
            $scope.loginView = false;
            $scope.formView = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
        else {
            $scope.loginView = true;
            $scope.formView = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        }

    }]);
```

And then create a reference to the controller with the `ng-controller` attribute. Your HTML should look as follows

```
<div ng-app="nh-launch">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-show="loginView">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="formView">
        <h1>Form</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok the only problem is that I am trying to show and hide the divs on the initial load. Is there a way I can do so using a controller? Sorry I am new to angular

Answer (score 0):

There must be a controller which should be bound with View. So the following code will help you to get:

```
  <div ng-app="nh-launch">
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <div ng-show="loginView">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="formView">
            <h1>Form</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script>
    angular.module('nh-launch',[]).controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope) {

        var token = "valid";

        if (token == "valid") {
            $scope.loginView = false;
            $scope.formView = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
        else {
            $scope.loginView = true;
            $scope.formView = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a separate controller (although you should use a controller and scope in real-world program).

You can inject the `$rootscope.  $scope.$apply` is not required.

I have tweaked your code 
https://jsfiddle.net/m1q7h9fn/8/

Comment: Your example is attaching everything to the `$rootScope`, if that page is built up than everything will have to go onto the `$rootScope` or be separate from the rest of the pages code that will eventually reside in a controller, attaching anything to `$rootScope` isn't good practice.  I wouldn't recommend anyone new to AngularJS to avoid controllers and attach everything to the `$rootScope`

Comment: yes, correct. Even I don't recommend. Please look at my answer (although you should use a controller in real-world program).

Comment: Yeah I get what you are saying, but you are giving a shortcut and suggesting the "long route". When someone is learning and wants to see the end result ASAP they are going to choose the shortcut, more often than not. Personally I wouldn't recommend giving that advice. But that's just me.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Always there is something to learn :) liked your idea. However I just wanted correct his code.